# Frontier Equation - Fit a polynomial to the top of a data set

Tags: python, optimization, cvxopt

How can I fit a polynomial to an empirical data set using python such that it fits the "top" of the data -- i.e. for every value of x, the output of function is greater than the largest y at that x.  But at the same time it minimizes this such that it hugs the data.  An example of what I'm referring to is seen in the image below:

[image: Frontier Equation Example]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `cvxopt` to find the coordinates of the efficient frontier, which is a quadratic programming problem, then feed those coordinates in numpy's [ployfit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) to get the polynomial fitting the frontier. This Quantopian blog post does both: https://blog.quantopian.com/markowitz-portfolio-optimization-2/